# Material UI Navbar Dropdown List

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I am currently trying to add an icon on my navbar that on click would drop down a list of notifications. I have found multiple code examples for drop-down menus but I haven't been able to use those to assist me or found any list-specific examples. Here is my current code with the menu application:

```
 const [auth, setAuth] = React.useState(true);
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setAuth(event.target.checked);
  };

  const handleMenu = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };


<div
        className="nav-links"
      >
        <IconButton
          size="large"
          aria-label="account of current user"
          aria-controls="menu-appbar"
          aria-haspopup="true"
          onClick={handleMenu}
          color="inherit"
        >
          {/* <NotificationsIcon /> */}
          <Avatar sx={{ bgcolor: deepOrange[500] }}>{user.displayName[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase()}</Avatar>
        </IconButton>
        <Menu
          id="menu-appbar"
          anchorEl={anchorEl}
          anchorOrigin={{
            vertical: 'center',
            horizontal: 'center',
          }}
          keepMounted
          transformOrigin={{
            vertical: 'center',
            horizontal: 'center',
          }}
          open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
          onClose={handleClose}
        >
          <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
        </Menu>
      </div>
```

[image: Navbar with icon]

[image: Navbar with icon clicked]

I would like a list (elements not clickable) to dropdown once the icon is clicked.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What's exactly your problem? Because I think that you are over complicating for nothing. Why can't you just set a proper state [open, setOpen] and use it to show or hide the dropdown? Here's what I mean:

```
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);const handleMenu = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
  setOpen(!open);
};

return (
    <div className="nav-links">
      <IconButton
        size="large"
        aria-label="account of current user"
        aria-controls="menu-appbar"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        onClick={handleMenu}
        color="inherit"
      >
        {/* <NotificationsIcon /> */}
        <Avatar sx={{ bgcolor: '#ccc' }}>FooBar</Avatar>
      </IconButton>
      <Menu
        id="menu-appbar"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: 'center',
          horizontal: 'center',
        }}
        keepMounted
        transformOrigin={{
          vertical: 'center',
          horizontal: 'center',
        }}
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: I'm actually trying not the use the <Menu> tag. The menu creates clickable links. I'm trying to add somewhat of a notification list that drops down. I can't figure out how to anchor the list and display it upon click of the account icon. The notification list doesn't need to be clickable.

Comment: Okay, what about setting `disabled={false}` in the <MenuItem> props?  That should transform you dropdown menu in a simple dropdown list. Be aware that you won't find that prop under the <MenuItem> docs because it's int the <ButtonBase> API page since "Props of the ButtonBase component are also available": https://mui.com/material-ui/api/button-base/